# Session not restoring over page refresh - endlessly nested object

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, redux

I am trying to use the redux-session library to store my apps state through page refreshes, however this is not working.

I have looked at the session object and it is getting the data, but populating quite slowly and endlessly nesting itself ie:

`session: { myobject: {}, session: { myobject: {data:2}, session: { myobject: {data:2}, session: {...`

By adding

```
   selectState (state) {
        return {
           user: state.toJS().session.myobject
       }; 
    }
```

The session seems correct (session in local storage is {myobject: {data:2}}), however if the page is reloaded then the session does not seem to be recovered before it is overwritten. There does not seem to be a working example of the library or any questions online about it.

```
/**
 * app.js
 *
 * This is the entry file for the application, only setup and boilerplate
 * code.
 */

// Needed for redux-saga es6 generator support
import 'babel-polyfill';

// Import all the third party stuff
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'react-router-redux';
import FontFaceObserver from 'fontfaceobserver';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import { createSession } from 'redux-session';
import 'sanitize.css/sanitize.css';

// Import root app
import App from 'containers/App';

// Import Language Provider
import LanguageProvider from 'containers/LanguageProvider';

// Load the favicon, the manifest.json file and the .htaccess file
/* eslint-disable import/no-webpack-loader-syntax */
import '!file-loader?name=[name].[ext]!./images/favicon.ico';
import '!file-loader?name=[name].[ext]!./images/icon-72x72.png';
import '!file-loader?name=[name].[ext]!./images/icon-96x96.png';
import '!file-loader?name=[name].[ext]!./images/icon-120x120.png';
import '!file-loader?name=[name].[ext]!./images/icon-128x128.png';
import '!file-loader?name=[name].[ext]!./images/icon-144x144.png';
import '!file-loader?name=[name].[ext]!./images/icon-152x152.png';
import '!file-loader?name=[name].[ext]!./images/icon-167x167.png';
import '!file-loader?name=[name].[ext]!./images/icon-180x180.png';
import '!file-loader?name=[name].[ext]!./images/icon-192x192.png';
import '!file-loader?name=[name].[ext]!./images/icon-384x384.png';
import '!file-loader?name=[name].[ext]!./images/icon-512x512.png';
import '!file-loader?name=[name].[ext]!./manifest.json';
import 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]!./.htaccess'; // eslint-disable-line import/extensions
/* eslint-enable import/no-webpack-loader-syntax */

import configureStore from './configureStore';

// Import i18n messages
import { translationMessages } from './i18n';

// Import CSS reset and Global Styles
import './global-styles';

// Observe loading of Open Sans (to remove open sans, remove the <link> tag in
// the index.html file and this observer)
const openSansObserver = new FontFaceObserver('Open Sans', {});

// When Open Sans is loaded, add a font-family using Open Sans to the body
openSansObserver.load().then(() => {
  document.body.classList.add('fontLoaded');
}, () => {
  document.body.classList.remove('fontLoaded');
});

// Create redux store with history
const initialState = {};
const history = createHistory();
const session = createSession({
    ns: 'dbwy1642b7c9e02q',
});

const store = configureStore(initialState, history, session);
const MOUNT_NODE = document.getElementById('app');

const render = (messages) => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <LanguageProvider messages={messages}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
          <App />
        </ConnectedRouter>
      </LanguageProvider>
    </Provider>,
    MOUNT_NODE
  );
};

if (module.hot) {
  // Hot reloadable React components and translation json files
  // modules.hot.accept does not accept dynamic dependencies,
  // have to be constants at compile-time
  module.hot.accept(['./i18n', 'containers/App'], () => {
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(MOUNT_NODE);
    render(translationMessages);
  });
}

// Chunked polyfill for browsers without Intl support
if (!window.Intl) {
  (new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve(import('intl'));
  }))
    .then(() => Promise.all([
      import('intl/locale-data/jsonp/en.js'),
      import('intl/locale-data/jsonp/de.js'),
    ]))
    .then(() => render(translationMessages))
    .catch((err) => {
      throw err;
    });
} else {
  render(translationMessages);
}

// Install ServiceWorker and AppCache in the end since
// it's not most important operation and if main code fails,
// we do not want it installed
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  require('offline-plugin/runtime').install(); // eslint-disable-line global-require
}
```

configureStore.js:

```
/**
 * Create the store with dynamic reducers
 */

import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import { fromJS } from 'immutable';
import { routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import createReducer from './reducers';

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

export default function configureStore(initialState = {}, history, session) {
  // Create the store with two middlewares
  // 1. sagaMiddleware: Makes redux-sagas work
  // 2. routerMiddleware: Syncs the location/URL path to the state
  const middlewares = [
      session,
    sagaMiddleware,
    routerMiddleware(history),
      thunkMiddleware
  ];

  const enhancers = [
    applyMiddleware(...middlewares),
  ];

  // If Redux DevTools Extension is installed use it, otherwise use Redux compose
  /* eslint-disable no-underscore-dangle */
  const composeEnhancers =
    process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' &&
    typeof window === 'object' &&
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__
      ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__({
        // TODO Try to remove when `react-router-redux` is out of beta, LOCATION_CHANGE should not be fired more than once after hot reloading
        // Prevent recomputing reducers for `replaceReducer`
        shouldHotReload: false,
      })
      : compose;
  /* eslint-enable */

  const store = createStore(
    createReducer(),
    fromJS(initialState),
    composeEnhancers(...enhancers)
  );

  // Extensions
  store.runSaga = sagaMiddleware.run;
  store.injectedReducers = {}; // Reducer registry
  store.injectedSagas = {}; // Saga registry

  // Make reducers hot reloadable, see http://mxs.is/googmo
  /* istanbul ignore next */
  if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept('./reducers', () => {
      store.replaceReducer(createReducer(store.injectedReducers));
    });
  }

  return store;
}
```

reducers.js

```
/**
 * Combine all reducers in this file and export the combined reducers.
 */

import { fromJS } from 'immutable';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux-immutable';
import { LOCATION_CHANGE } from 'react-router-redux';

import languageProviderReducer from 'containers/LanguageProvider/reducer';
import userReducer from 'containers/App/reducer';

/*
 * routeReducer
 *
 * The reducer merges route location changes into our immutable state.
 * The change is necessitated by moving to react-router-redux@5
 *
 */

// Initial routing state
const routeInitialState = fromJS({
  location: null,
});

/**
 * Merge route into the global application state
 */
function routeReducer(state = routeInitialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    /* istanbul ignore next */
    case LOCATION_CHANGE:
      return state.merge({
        location: action.payload,
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

/*Session reducer*/

function sessionReducer (state = {}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'LOAD_STORED_STATE':
            return action.storedState;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

/**
 * Creates the main reducer with the dynamically injected ones
 */
export default function createReducer(injectedReducers) {
  return combineReducers({
      route: routeReducer,
      session: sessionReducer,
      language: languageProviderReducer,
      user: userReducer,

    ...injectedReducers,
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> no idea why state.toJS().myobject is {}

Fast code analysis shows that nothing had been restored from `localStorage` when `redux` store is created. At every code points `initialState` is always `{}`, so it's expected that store will have empty object.

Maybe following code should be refactored to check `localStorage` state and maybe load or merge with it. Also, there is no preloaded state from server side.

```
export default function configureStore(initialState = {}, history, session) {
  // [cut]
  const store = createStore(
    createReducer(),
    fromJS(initialState),
    composeEnhancers(...enhancers)
  );
  // [cut]
  return store;
}
```

Comment: Surely it is more complicated than that because if there is nothing in local storage than it is supposed to use cookies (that was the description of redux-session)? I more or less see what you are saying, but is this not what the library is supposed to be handling? I can’t find any good examples to do what you are saying so I am a little lost... redux-session could use some example code

Comment: Sorry, I am getting I little further. I have removed initialState as that was part of my old code, however composeEnhancers(...enhancers) should be adding in applyMiddleware(session), which I thought should be restoring the session?

Comment: I believe the issue is a conflict with the other reducers replacing the state. Thanks!